# (Xamarin Forms) Can't use Bold, Italic, etc... of TEditor version 1.0.3 on Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using [TEditor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TEditor/) version `1.0.3` of Xamarin Forms `3.6.0.220655`.

But on Android seems `TEditor` is not work, I can't use Bold, Italic, etc... on **Toolbar** of `TEditor`.

[Image_bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAch0.png)

I try debug on Library `TEditor`. Can error at method **SetBold()** of file **TEditorAPI.cs**:

```
    public void SetBold()
    {
        string trigger = @"zss_editor.setFontWeight('bold');";
        _javaScriptEvaluatFunc.Invoke(trigger);
    }
```

Content of method **SetBold()** link to file **ZSSRichTextEditor.js** of library. But this is code JavaScript, I can debug it:

```
zss_editor.setBold = function() {
document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
zss_editor.enabledEditingItems();}
```

How to fix this bug?

If you need source library, I will supply it to you.

**Source code**: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R0BJXXfmA9FAb6DCELXbBFGii_avhnmx/view?usp=sharing

Please help me!

Thanks!

GitHub: [TEditor 1.0.3](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor)

Comment: What exactly does not "work"?

Comment: @SushiHangover I took photo bug in description. Please help me!

Comment: I did.. For the Android TEditor, it looks fine to me....

Comment: I don't know why I can't Bold, Italic, etc... on HTML Editor. I will find solution for it. Thanks @SushiHangover

Comment: Are you talking about customizing the toolbar? i.e. https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor#custom

Comment: @SushiHangover, Do you not know my question? You should view my image `Image_bug` in content description. Toolbar HTML Editor is disable, I can click it to use (Bold, Italic, etc...).

Comment: @SushiHangover I updated question... Can you answer my question? Thanks!

Comment: I just cloned the TEditor repo and tried the "Sample" app and it works fine. You might want to try it and start making your changes from there.

Comment: @SushiHangover On Android, When you use HTML Editor, Can you use bold, italic for text HTML?

Why? I can't use bold, italic when I open page HTML Editor?

Comment: Yes, using the sample app running on an Android device, I can highlight the characters and touch the B/I/U/... buttons in the toolbar to change the text... If you are editing within somethings that is B/I/U than that text has the same attributes applied

Comment: @SushiHangover But when you touch the Bold or Italic buttons in the toolbar, Text is focused that bold or italic? I can touch the Bold or Italic buttons in the toolbar, but text is focused that don't change

Comment: No sure what you mean by "..text is focused...`, you mean mean the currently highlighted (selected) text, then, yes, it changes for me when touch the toolbar buttons.

Comment: @SushiHangover you can show your video demo! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, You is using old version of lib `TEditor`.

this is old version of [Old TEditor](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor)

You should update it:

This is new version => [New TEditor](https://github.com/SymplastLLC/TEditor)

New version of lib was fixed this bug.

But After fix it, on iOS can't use "**bold**" for first.

Because change file **ZSSRichTextEditor.js** will work with Android, but iOS don't work.

So, You should separate method **LoadResources()** at file **TEditor.Abstractions/TEditor.cs** for Android and iOS.